# split then add to array working before then suddenly not working

Tags: excel, vba

i have a code below it was working fine then suddenly the line `arr = split(cell.Value, ",")` has an error wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment i just inserted the `lastRow` variable, even if i changed the range something fixed like `A1:A10` it is still the same error

```
Sub split()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim arr() As String
        Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
        
        lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = Range("A1:A" & lastRow) ' Range of cells to check
        
        For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, ",") = 0 Then
                Cells(cell.Row, 3) = cell.Value
                Cells(cell.Row, 1) = ""
            Else
                arr = split(cell.Value, ",") ' Split cell value by comma and add to array
            
                For i = UBound(arr) To 0 Step -1
                     If UBound(arr) = 2 Then
                     Cells(cell.Row, i + 1) = arr(i)
                     Else
                     Cells(cell.Row, i + 2) = arr(i)
                     Cells(cell.Row, 1) = ""
                     End If
                Next i
               End If
               End If
        Next cell
        
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the danger of using names for subs/variables that already exist in the VBA code/naming syntax. Your error is caused by it thinking you're trying to call your own sub recursively.

Notice how it's a small `s` unlike `Split()` but your sub doesn't take any arguments hence that error. Change the name of your sub and adjust your line to `arr = Split(cell.Value, ",")` and it should be fixed.

Comment: i did not realized that i did rename the sub also

Comment: Is it fixed with the changes I suggested?